# How to delete all the records a particular table, but except last 6 months data

Tags: sql, command

I have a production table called Message Order with columns like MessageID, CountryID, status, created,etc.

Now i need to delete all the the records but except last 6 months data not be deleted. Deletion part is based on countryID.

created column is date

for eg: i will give countryID as 89 ,

can someone please help with the efficient way of deleting.

Thanks

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you will using.  Please explain "Deletion part is based on countryID."  I am guessing that this is important, but the sentence doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You would want something like this:

```
delete from message_order
    where companyid = 89 and
          created < current_date - interval '6 month';
```

The date functions are database specific.  In Oracle, it would look like:

```
where created < add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6)
```

In MySQL:

```
where created < current_date - interval 6 month
```

Comment: Thank you for Answer :) .. we are using oracle environment.

Comment: @VarunKM . . . Then I think this answers your question.